# MySQL Return all unique values in a column along with the last date associated with each

Tags: mysql

I have a table `relative` from which I am trying to pull all the unique `ID`s as well as the first and last date associated with each one.  So far, I have the query below, which returns each unique `ID` along with the first date in the table associated with each `ID`.  How could I modify this query (or run a second one) that would return each unique `ID` along with the last date in the table associated with that `ID`?

```
SELECT  `ID`, `Date` FROM `relative`.`datatable` GROUP BY `ID`
```

Comment: Note that I don't think `GROUP BY` is guaranteed to give the first date.

Comment: Is not correct use GROUP BY and then put in the select field list, fields not present in the group by (as youe Date field). Can you add in your question an example data set and want do you want show?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a basic aggregation query:

```
SELECT  `ID`, min(`Date`), max(`date`)
FROM `relative`.`datatable`
GROUP BY `ID`;
```

And, as @rogoas points out, your query is not guaranteed to return the minimum date.  It will return an *arbitrary* date for each id.

Comment: I was about to post an answer using `ORDER BY`; this is much better

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with [min(date)](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-min-function.htm) and [max(date)](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-max-function.htm):-

```
SELECT  `ID`, min(`Date`), max(`date`) FROM `relative`.`datatable`
GROUP BY `ID`;
```